# Advance formula field

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to use the following code snippet in a formula field

case_category__c (multi-select picklist field), 
email_categoty__c (multi-select picklist field)

```
if(case_category__c != null/blank && email_categoty__c== null/blank){
   //do something
}
else if(case_category__c == null/blank && email_categoty__c!= null/blank){
   //do something
}
else
   // error
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are having? you need to check picklists for `null`?

Comment: @highfive : yes, I've to check picklist value for null, also how to use && operator here in this scenario?

Comment: you need to have a formula field or a validation rule? confuse with your question and code snippet

Comment: @highfive: I have to use formula field.

There is a Formula field "Final_Value__c" which is depended on case_category__c (Picklist), email_categoty__c (pick list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF( Ispickval(case_category__c  ,"") &&  NOT(ISPICKVAL(email_categoty__c  ,"")), "First Condition",
 IF( Ispickval(email_categoty__c  ,"") &&  NOT(ISPICKVAL(case_category__c  ,"")), "Second Condition","Else Condition"))
```

Just an untested code. Get the idea behind.

Comment: Yeah, logic is right. I got the idea. In fact, I have implemented. But, though these fields are multi select picklist value, so only few functions are supported.

Comment: Did you try `ISBLANK` ? Sorry, can't test these right now.
`IF(  ISBLANK(case_category__c)  &&  NOT(ISBLANK(email_categoty__c)), "First Condition",
 IF( ISBLANK(email_categoty__c) &&  NOT(ISBLANK(case_category__c)), "Second Condition","Else Condition"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF( Ispickval(case_category__c  ,"") &&  NOT(ISPICKVAL(email_categoty__c  ,"")), "YES", "No")
```

Comment: I have to use Formula field (return type TEXT).
This formula field is depended upon case category and email category.

If case_category__c != null and email_categoty__c == null then Final_Value__c = "CASE"

Comment: I don't know if I understood you're question right. Please find the above edited answer. Substitute "yes" and "no" with your requirement.

Comment: Please let me know if that doesn't work in your case.

Comment: both the fields are multi-select picklist field. multi-select picklist fields only support
INCLUDES
ISBLANK
ISNULL
ISCHANGED 
PRIORVALUE
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution:

```
IF(
AND(
ISBLANK(Email_Category__c), NOT(ISBLANK(Case_Category__c)) 
) , 'CASE',  IF(
AND(
ISBLANK(Case_Category__c), NOT(ISBLANK(Email_Category__c)) 
) , 'EMAIL', 
'ERROR'
) 
)
```